# mulitple when conditions with fluent validation

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

i need to specify multiple conditions in a 'when' clause for fv.

so i want to do this

```
When(day => day.sunny.Equals(false) and  day.rain.Equals(true), () =>
    {
        //rules would go in here
    });
```

Clearly the 'and' wont work but i cant find an example of the correct syntax.

Answer (score 10):

Sounds like you want:

```
When(day => day.sunny.Equals(false) && day.rain.Equals(true), () =>
{
    // Stuff
});
```

It's just normal C#, after all.

By the way, if `sunny` and `rain` are just `bool` values, I think this is far more readable:

```
When(day => !day.sunny && day.rain, () =>
{
    // Stuff
});
```